# wso2 carbon messagebox on receive message : failed to get secret it of user

Tags: messagebox, wso2, amazon-sqs

I'm working on WSO2 Carbon MessageBox(SQS) in order to subscribe a queue and then read the messages from messagebox for batch processing.

There are some useful tutorials like :

http://wso2.org/project/message-broker/1.0.2/docs/samples/messagebox_as_event_sink.html

And they are working successfully when trying to connect to a MessageBox on the local WSO2 ESB instance.

However it is failing when receiving messages from the MessageBox with same configuration on a remote WSO2 instance.

These are the log messages on WSO2 ESB.

Authentication looks ok (second log message) but, `"ReceiveMessage"` request is failing in `AuthenticationHandler`.

> ```
> TID: [] [WSO2 ESB] [2012-07-12 09:49:19,597] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine} - Failed to get secret id of user
> ```
>
> 41ca9541e96a077766d2
>   {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine}org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Failed
>   to get secret id of user 41ca9541e96a077766d2 at
>   org.wso2.carbon.messagebox.sqs.internal.module.AuthenticationHandler.invoke(AuthenticationHandler.java:80)
>   at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340) at
>   org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313) at
>   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262) at
>   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:168) at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:199)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) at
>   org.wso2.carbon.bridge.BridgeServlet.service(BridgeServlet.java:164)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.server.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:154)
>   at org.wso2.carbon.server.TomcatServer$1.invoke(TomcatServer.java:254)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:396)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:356)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1534)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>
> ```
>  TID: [] [WSO2 ESB] [2012-07-12 09:49:19,401] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -
> ```
>
> 'admin' logged in at [2012-07-12 09:49:19,0401] from IP address
>   
>   {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil

Am I doing something wrong or need to do some specific configuration?

Answer (score 0):

if your message box in a remote machine then your http request should have the authentication header as specified by the SQS specification. This seems like you have not send a valid request with a user name and secret id. And also sqs:// will only work in local environments.

Comment: Well, I can do the authentication and read sqs keys.
I'm putting accessKeyId, timestamp and signature exactly as it is in the sample code. For connection I'm not using sqs://, the url that is displayed on the WSO2 management console, something like :

https://<IP_ADDRESS>:9443/services/MessageQueue/admin/test

which parameter could be invalid or missing?